# Using same data provider for all the test methods

Tags: testng

I have a couple of test cases which runs on multiple servers. I have a property file which contains all the details of a particular server. I have a separate property file for each of our server. During execution I have to pass the environment file name and the test classes will pick it up.
But now I want to achieve parallel execution on multiple servers. I have used @factory but I need to write the same lines of code in all my test classes.
Is there any way to separate @factory and all test classes extends it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way for resources, environment and test data management. You can take a look to [QAF-testNG extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks) Where you can [manage resources](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/managing_resources_for_different_env.html) for multiple environments and [configure](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/creating_configuration_file.html) at run-time. For example:

```
env.resource=resources/common;resources/qa1
```

There are [inbuilt data providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) as well that can be dynamically configured using properties or parameters. For example: `datafile="resources/${env}/tc01.txt"`.